# How to avoid a rmd file to execute the entire R script every time I knit it to pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr

Here is the question:

In **file.r** I ran an extensive analysis based on a huge dataset.
Every time I open the file I just need to load the libraries and everything is ready.
I don't need to download anymore any of the dataset inputs I need.

Now I have created a RMD **file.rmd** with the same code of **file.r** to present its findings.
I'm trying to get a preview of how the pdf will look like.
The problem is that when I click "Knit to pdf", it starts to download all the packages and datasets again. I have to wait hours to see the effects of small changes in code.

And there is more:
Some objects created in R file simply are not working in the rmd file.

Ex: in R file I coded: 
`edx2 <- edx2 %>% mutate(timeRr = yearRating - release)`

When I try to run the same code in the rmd file I get the message:
**Error in Func(x[[i]],...) : object 'timeRr' not found calls:  f -> scales_add_defaults - > lapply - > fun**
The same libraries loaded in both files (r and rmd)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can add `eval=FALSE` to Rmd chunks that don't need to be run, or `cache=TRUE` to chunks that only need to run when something has changed. Your second issue: most likely `timeRr` exists in your R environment, but not in the Rmd environment for some reason _e.g._ the code required to generate it is not present.

Comment: Thanks, Neil. But it didn't worked. I put ```{r, cache=TRUE}``` in every important R chunk, but the rmd file keeps doing everything from scratch (downloading, etc) when I knit it to pdf.

With regards to the 2nd issue: The rmd contains the code that creates the timeRr variable, as follows:
```edx2 <- edx2 %>% mutate(timeRr = yearRating - release)```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you running this in Rstudio or via the command line e.g. `rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd")`

Comment: Jared: I'm running everything in RStudio. A tab for the R file and another tab for rmd file.

Answer (score 1):

1) At the end of the data analysis (file.R), save the data you need for the Notebook in a .RDS file.

For example, if you generated 3 results : res1, res2 and res3

```
results <- list(res1 = res1, res2 = res2, res3 = res3)
saveRDS(file = 'results.RDS', results)
```

2) instead of sourcing the analysis script, just read the results in the Notebook (.Rmd)

```
data <- readRDS('results.RDS')
# Results available for further use in the Notebook
data$res1
data$res2
data$res3
```

The error you get with edx2 is probably due to the fact that a new session is opened during generation of a notebook : are you sure that file.R really generates edx2, or is it only available in your current session?

Comment: Thanks, Waldi. But it didn't work. It keeps returning the error that timeRr was not found, but I don't understand:

 The RMD file has all the instructions to run all the code (I copied exactly from R file). **The first chunk** on rmd installs and loads the libraries. **The second** downloads the dataset. The **third chunk** transforms the downloaded data into edx2. 

So the RMD file  should have all the chunks it needs to create from scratch the timeRr variable. And it needs to be so in order to everyone who runs the RMDfile get the same results I've got.

Comment: @ValdirSantos, can you try as I suggested you : 1) run the R script independently of .Rmd, at the end check that edx2 is present in your environment and save it in a .RDS. In the .Rmd, just load the .RDS, it should work.